# C# Close program/form with a Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

Okay so I have a C# form with a couple of classes. In one of these classes I'm running a Thread to check if an external program is running. When the external program isn't running I want my program to close.

I'm a bit of a novice so to me the obvious answer is to use form.Close(). But I am not sure if it is possible to access this function from a subclass or even a different thread!

So my questions are: (how) is it possible to close the form from a different thread in an other class? More important is this best practice?

Comment: check this : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/2cb9cd98-b638-4378-9349-fbb6598e5092/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Control.InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) and [`Control.BeginInvoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) in order to call a method on the UI thread.

For example (this method has to be inside the form class itself):

```
public void CloseForm()
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(this.Close));
    }
    else
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

This is safe to call from another thread.